# Can the Coldfusion onRequestEnd handler read or write the client bound response stream?

Tags: coldfusion

Given a Coldfusion page generates some content (html, xml, json, whatever) to satisfy a client request, can the onRequestEnd handler read (or write) the content in the response stream?  If so, how?

If it matters assume Coldfusion 8 on IIS 6.

Thanks for looking
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetPageContext().getCFOutput() seems to do what I need e.g.

```
<cfset oldContent = GetPageContext().getCFOutput().getString()>
<cfset GetPageContext().getCFOutput().clearBuffer()>

<cfset newContent = ModifyContent(oldContent)>
<cfset GetPageContext().getCFOutput().print(newContent)>
```

Comment: In the onRequestEnd() handler . . .

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
According to the docs: [ColdFusion 8 onRequestEnd](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/AppEvents_09.html)

> This method has the same purpose as the onRequestEnd.cfm page. (You
>   cannot use an onRequestEnd.cfm page if you have an Application.cfc
>   file for your application.) **This method runs before the request
>   terminates; therefore, it can access the page context, and can
>   generate output.**
>
> This method can access the requested page’s Variables scope only if
>   the Application.cfc file includes an onRequest method that calls the
>   page. You can use Request scope variables to share data with the
>   requested page, even if the Application.cfc file does not have an
>   onRequest method.